# Configure a one directional relationship in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Model

HUBS -< SECTIONS

sections are a tree hierarchy but they all belong to a hub (there is another table managing the hierarchy as one section can appear twice in the tree)

A hub should also have a root section, so on my hub entity I have:

```
public partial class Hub
{
    public Hub()
    {
        this.Sections = new List<Section>();
    }

    public int HubId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }

    public int RootSectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section RootSection { get; set; }
}
```

If I don't set an mapping as per:

```
public class HubMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Hub>
{
    public HubMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.HubId);


        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Hubs");
        this.Property(t => t.HubId).HasColumnName("HubId");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Site)
            .WithMany(t => t.Hubs)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SiteId);

     }
}
```

I get an error about not finding RootSection_SectionId column. Now I could just rename the column to match, but in the interests of my understanding of EF mapping, I'd like to be able to specify they column, which is "RootSectionId"

What would I need to include in the mapping file to map this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.RootSection)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RootSectionId);
```